# Mysterious divider between ViewPager Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, material-design

I've been designing a small app and I'm quite new to using a ViewPager.

When transitioning between specific fragments (Tuesday and Wednesday, Sunday and Monday) I sometimes get this grey border appearing from apparently nowhere. I was hoping someone might be able to tell me how I can remove this?

This is the [border I was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt0oX.png)

This is my XML file for styles:

```
<resources>
<!--Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/DowningBarStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="DowningBarStyle"     parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

All help is greatly appreciated and if any other snippets of my code would be useful I'll post them if needed.

Comment: it looks like a scrollbar to me

Comment: it is a scrollbar to the tuesday fragment.

Comment: @Blackbelt Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez Thank you to you as well, such a stupid oversight from me.

Comment: This question should be then closed, as there is no issue to solve....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a listview or spinner for populating a single day's data try putting

android:scrollbars="none" in it.